# Criar projetos VSIX no Visual Studio Professional

Tags: visual-studio, template

Eu criava templates para o `Visual Studio` na versão `Ultimate`, mas por alguns motivos precisei migrar para o `Visual Studio Professional`, e desde então os meus projetos `VSIX` não funcionam mais.

As extensões para baixar no `visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com` ao serem instaladas no `VS Premium` dizem que "não podem ser instaladas nesta versão da aplicação".

Então, há alguma forma de manipular projetos VSIX no Visual Studio Professional, sem ser na mão e nem usar o VS Ultimate?